# Overloaded operator-() to return difference between two dates

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

The operator is supposed to return the difference between two dates. The problem arises when the date passed is greater than the default date: 3/31/2010. It always returns one less day than it is supposed to. Which means, passing (3/31/2010) and (4/1/2010) both return 0 days, passing (4/2/2010) returns 1 days, (when in fact, it should return 2 days) and so on. I could've worked around the problem with an if() but as I said, both of those dates return the same difference so I can't use that to distinguish them. Any help is appreciated.

```
Date Date::operator-(Date d2)
{
    Date diff;
    int totaldays1, totaldays2, diffIndays;
    totaldays1 = (year*365)+(month*30)+(day);
    totaldays2 = (d2.year*365)+(d2.month*30)+(d2.day);
    diffIndays = totaldays2 - totaldays1;
    diff.year  = diffIndays/365;
    diff.month = (diffIndays-(diff.year*365))/30;
    diff.day   = diffIndays - (diff.year*365) - (diff.month*30);
    cout<<"\n"<<totaldays1;
    cout<<"\n"<<totaldays2<<"\n";
    return diff;
}

int main()
{
    Date d1(3,31,2010); //31 March, 2010
    Date d2;
    Date d3;
    int diffInDays;
    d3 = d2 - d1;
    diffInDays = abs(d3.getDay())+abs(d3.getMonth()*30)+abs(d3.getYear()*365);
    cout<<"Difference between "<<d1<<" & "<<d2<<" = "
    << abs(diffInDays)<<" days.";
}
```

Comment: Your code assumes every month has 30 days in it.

Comment: Is `ctime` not good enough for you?

Comment: On the same note as what HolyBlackCat said, you're also neglecting to take into account leap years.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks. I knew it was something really dumb.

Comment: @LouisGo This was for an assignment where we are supposed to do this ourselves (without using lib functions)

Comment: How come a difference between two dates is also a date? This makes no sense. A date is a point in time and a difference between dates is a time interval. These are two very different things.

Comment: The difference between 2010-04-01 and 2010-03-31 is *one day*. One day is not a date. (And neither is "the first day of the zeroth month of the zeroth year".)

Comment: For those stating how the difference between two dates cannot be a date, I'm aware it doesn't make logical sense, but this is just how implemented it, and is working for me in this context (as the operator-() is used between two dates, Idk how I would otherwise, store the result in another datatype)